# Python - submodule loading detection

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, python-module

I am currently working on a library that patches several other modules upon loading. It mostly works fine, however in some cases it runs into the problem when the functions to be patched are contained in a sub-module that needs to be explicitely loaded. For instance in `scikits-learn`, the sub-module `datasets` has the following behavior:

```
>>> import sklearn
>>> dir(sklearn)
['__SKLEARN_SETUP__', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__check_build', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', 'base', 'clone', 'externals', 're', 'setup_module', 'sys', 'utils', 'warnings']
```

It only loads it in case when dataset was explicitely loaded:

```
>>> from sklearn import datasets
>>> dir(sklearn)
['__SKLEARN_SETUP__', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__check_build', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', 'base', 'clone', 'datasets', 'externals', 'feature_extraction', 'preprocessing', 're', 'setup_module', 'sys', 'utils', 'warnings']
```

How can I detect when dataset is explicitely imported in order to launch my patching only when this sub-module is loaded?

Comment: You are using a custom import hook ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Nope - Just inserting the patching objects into `sys.meta_path`

Comment: That's what I meant - post some code

Comment: Question related to: https://github.com/recipy/recipy/issues/170 and the module that contains functions relevant to the issue is in https://github.com/recipy/recipy/blob/master/recipyCommon/utils.py - `patch_function`, applied from https://github.com/recipy/recipy/blob/master/recipy/PatchSimple.py `patch` method. The actual insertion is done by inserting specific PatchSimple subclasses into `sys.meta_path`, such as in https://github.com/recipy/recipy/blob/master/recipy/PatchScientific.py

Comment: And the https://github.com/recipy/recipy/blob/master/recipy/PatchImporter.py actually contains the `find_module` and `load_module` methods that do the heavy lifting once the module is in the `sys.meta_path`.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D  - so the relevant code is a bit spread around; I could try to extract relevant code paths and post them here, but if there are no canonical way of doing it, maybe it isn't exactly the best question for StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes please update the question with your comments citing especially https://github.com/recipy/recipy/blob/deb404b34dca684a4068b355f67e84ce26e4a4f6/recipy/PatchScientific.py#L20-L29. Never link to branches link to commits as I do here (hit y in the github UI)

Comment: good to know - will do